# Array values reset problem with dynamic allocation

Tags: c++

Trying to create a little program using class, dynamic allocation,...
This is the "problematic" code:

```
void Social::calc_pop(double years) const {
    double var = births - deaths;
    double* pop = new double;
    pop[0] = pop_0;
    for (int i = 0; i < years; i++)
    {
        pop[i+1] = pop[i] + var;
        std::cout << "La popolazione all'anno " << i+1 << " è pari a " << pop[i+1] << std::endl;
    }
    delete pop;
}
```

The output is (with years = 10, pop_0 = 300, births = 10, deaths = 9):

```
pop[1] = 301
pop[2] = 302
pop[3] = 303
pop[4] = 304
pop[5] = 1
pop[6] = 1
pop[7] = 1
pop[8] = 2
pop[9] = 3
pop[10] = 4
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why is `years` a `double`?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't be a double.

Comment: @sungfive If you really need a dynamically managed array for this, use a `std::vector<double>` in c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
double* pop = new double;
```

allocates a single `double`, but then you are treating `pop` like an array, which invokes undefined behavior when you index into it at any position other than 0.

Instead, you need to allocate an array:

```
double* pop = new double[years + 1];
```

Note that you need to make `years` an `int`, or cast it to an `int` inside the `new` expression.

which is later deleted like this:

```
delete [] pop;
```

---

However, please don't write this code (unless you're just practicing how dynamic allocation works). You can save yourself a lot of trouble by just making `pop` a vector:

```
std::vector<double> pop(years + 1);
```

Comment: It return me this: "error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type"

Comment: `years` needs to be an `int`, or at least cast to an `int` in the `new` expression. Added that to the answer.

Comment: Right, double years made no sense with int i.

Comment: @cigien Please don't advise `new` / `delete` for dynamic memory management in c++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I wasn't actually advising it, just answering the question. But you're right; I added a note suggesting vector instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're only allocating a single `double`, which you treat as an array, and that has undefined behaviour if the index is greater than zero.
You also can't allocate an array of `years` elements, because `years` is not an integer – what would an array of 3.125 `double`s look like?

You don't need any kind of collection for this calculation, only the last known value.

```
void Social::calc_pop(int years) const {
    double var = births - deaths;
    double pop = pop_0;
    for (int i = 0; i < years; i++)
    {
        pop = pop + var;
        std::cout << "La popolazione all'anno " << i+1 << " è pari a " << pop << std::endl;
    }
}
```